# Why my Gandi apex/naked/bare domain doesn't work with my Heroku app?

Tags: domain-name-system, heroku

Here are my current settings:

### Heroku

```
myapp:~/workspace/myapp (master) $ heroku domains
=== cute-name-99999 Heroku Domain
cute-name-99999.herokuapp.com

=== cute-name-99999 Custom Domains
Domain Name     DNS Target
──────────────  ─────────────────────────────────
myapp.ch      myapp.ch.herokudns.com
*.myapp.ch    wildcard.myapp.ch.herokudns.com
www.myapp.ch  www.myapp.ch.herokudns.com
myapp:~/workspace/myapp (master) $
```

### Gandi ([my DNS provider](http://gandi.net/))

Zone file:

```
@ 10800 IN A 217.70.184.38
blog 10800 IN CNAME blogs.vip.gandi.net.
imap 10800 IN CNAME access.mail.gandi.net.
pop 10800 IN CNAME access.mail.gandi.net.
smtp 10800 IN CNAME relay.mail.gandi.net.
webmail 10800 IN CNAME webmail.gandi.net.
www 10800 IN CNAME www.myapp.ch.herokudns.com.
@ 10800 IN MX 50 fb.mail.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN MX 10 spool.mail.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:_mailcust.gandi.net ?all"
```

Web Forwarding (added 15:40 London time):

```
Enabled as Permanent
http://myapp.ch -> http://www.myapp.ch
```

According Gandi support, "A web forwarding can take from 20 minutes to activate (time to update the redirection server) up to 3 hours or more if the DNS zone file has to be updated.". Well, these zone file settings has more than 12 hours. Currently, `http://www.myapp.ch` is accessible, but `http://myapp.ch` is not. I already empty my cache browser. Is there something else to check or should I just wait more time?

Comment: Contact support again and tell them it has been 12 hours?

Comment: sure, but they didn't answered me yet.

Comment: I'm not sure what else you imagine we can offer. Maybe if you de-censor the domain name we can take a look and see if it's working for us.